# Cumulative sum algorithm that worked on parallel computing

Tags: parallel-computing

Compared to "vectors addition" which can naturally work independently for the summation of each of its corresponding elements, it allows parallel work by processors. Example:

```
[1 2 3] + [4 5 6] = [5 7 9]
```

Which only requires 1 iteration.

How to make the "cumulative sum" operation algorithm work in parallel on a vector? Consider the following sequential cumulative sum problem:
Give vector

```
a_vector := [1 2 3]
empty_vector := []
Step 1 -> [1]
Step 2 -> [1 3]
Step 3 -> [1 3 6]
```

Those steps filling up the empty vector.
So it takes 3 iterations longer.

Though both produce the same number of elements as the number of elements in its operand, so it can be said that both are elementwise operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parallel [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) algorithm. See Wikipedia for some examples.